# inner join com subselect codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Como criar uma função que traga o mesmo resultado da query abaixo usando o codeigniter?

```
SELECT AC.cod_setor,AC.cod_coletor ,SUM(ac.quantidade) AS quantidade 
FROM item_inventarios AC 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT cod_setor , SUM(quantidade) AS quantidade FROM item_inventarios GROUP BY cod_setor HAVING COUNT(distinct cod_setor + cod_coletor) > 1 ) AC2 ON AC2.cod_setor = AC.cod_setor 
where `id_inventario`='37' 
GROUP BY AC.cod_setor , AC.cod_coletor
```

Comment: não seria porque o `\`id_inventario\`` está entre aspas (e é considerado uma string)?

Comment: rLinhares, no exemplo que postei esta dessa maneira, mas no codeigniter ficara assim; 
->get_where("item_inventarios", array(
                 "id_inventario"=> $id
                ))->result_array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver com o código abaixo;

```
  //campos do select
        $this->db->select('AC.cod_setor, AC.cod_coletor, SUM(ac.quantidade) AS quantidade');
        // tabela from
        $this->db->from('item_inventarios AC');
        // join
        $this->db->join('(SELECT cod_setor, SUM(quantidade) AS quantidade FROM item_inventarios GROUP BY cod_setor HAVING COUNT(distinct cod_setor + cod_coletor) > 1 ) AC2'
                , 'AC2.cod_setor = AC.cod_setor', 'inner');

        $where['id_inventario'] = $id;
        //where
        $this->db->where(array('id_inventario' => $id));

        //group by
        $this->db->group_by('AC.cod_setor , AC.cod_coletor');

        // executa a query e retorna um vetor de resultados
        $resultado_query = $this->db->get('')->result_array();
        echo $this->db->last_query(); //COMENTAR PARA NÃO MOSTRAR O SELECT
        return $resultado_query;
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Ao invés de escrever o nome da tabela no primeiro parâmetro do `join()` você precisa escrever o seu `SELECT` monstro que produz a tabela para o join. Pena que escrever tanto assim pode gerar uma incompatibilidade se trocar de banco. A instrução `inner` fica por último nos parâmetros.

```
$this->db->select('AC.cod_setor, AC.cod_coletor, SUM(ac.quantidade) AS quantidade');
$this->db->from('item_inventarios AC');
$this->db->join('(SELECT cod_setor, SUM(quantidade) AS quantidade FROM item_inventarios GROUP BY cod_setor HAVING COUNT(distinct cod_setor + cod_coletor) > 1 )', 'AC2.cod_setor = AC.cod_setor', 'inner');
$this->db->where('id_inventario', 37);
$this->db->group_by('AC.cod_setor , AC.cod_coletor');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Para depurar se seu comando SQL foi construído perfeitamente, utilize: `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: E como ficaria essa parte? 
 
where `id_inventario`='37' 
GROUP BY AC.cod_setor , AC.cod_coletor

Comment: Esqueci de incluir. Incrementei.